# Why Apache HTTP server have 2 process showing on Task Manager?

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

Here is my system configuration.

Hardware info 
 - core i3 
 - 4 GB RAM
Software info 
 - Xampp V 3.2.1
 - Windows 64bit

Comment: These are parent and child processes. Read the docs. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#page-header

Comment: just out of curiousity - have you tried typing your question into a *search engine* first? because the first two results (after the one leading to this question) *would have completely answered it*. SO is supposed to be the *last* resort for questions, not the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Apache's documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#page-header):

> Because Apache for Windows is multithreaded, it does not use a
>   separate process for each request, as Apache can on Unix. Instead
>   there are usually only two Apache processes running: a parent process,
>   and a child which handles the requests. Within the child process each
>   request is handled by a separate thread.